# How to calculate minimum amount of coins for a monetary amount?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a homework assignment in which I have to calculate the minimum amount of coins required for an inputted monetary value.

I've been trying to wrap my head round the logic involved, but I can't quite grasp it. I copied most of it from this website, so if you could explain it to me, I'd be very grateful!

First I tried loads of if, else statements and I knew I had to use % (modulus). But it didn't really work.

```
n1=float(input("Enter a monetary amount: "))

n1=n1*100

pound=0
fiftyp=0
twentyp=0
tenp=0
onep=0

pound=n1/100
n1%=100

fiftyp=n1/50
n1%=50

twentyp=n1/20 
n1%=20

tenp=n1/10 
n1%=10

onep=n1

print(int(pound), int(fiftyp), int(twentyp), int(tenp), int(onep))
```

This code, however, **doesn't work**, probably due to rounding issues? For example, when inputted 2.30, it outputted 2 0 1 0 9, i.e. 2pounds twenty pence and nine pence, when it should be 2 0 1 1 0, i.e. 2pounds twenty pence, ten pence.

Again, if you could also help me understand how the bulk of the above code works, I'd be very grateful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How would you do this using a pencil and paper? Figure that out, and then make an effort to write the code for it.

Comment: Although I totally agree with Ken's comment, the issue is not in the coding itself, but in how Python does arithmetic.

Enter 0.1*3 in your terminal and see what comes out.

I am not going to give you a direct answer though, google on that and once you understand why this happens, you can use logic to go around the issue.

Comment: @Gonzalez87 Thank you for the suggestions. I'll give it a try!